# No module named 'pandas' after installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I only have one version of Python installed on my computer. pip list indicates I have Pandas, Numpy installed etc. The "where python" command shows the correct root folder for Python, and I have manually checked in the \lib folder that the packages are indeed there..

What could cause this "No module named pandas" error?

[image: Pandas no module found]

Comment: do you have multiple python installed?

Comment: I would suggest you to work inside virtual environment , now i don't know which python is sublime detecting it should not be that much of a problem.you can find easy guides on how to setup virtualenv for python check if it works inside that or not

Comment: Not that I know of!

Comment: Check your PYTHONPATH, and PATH. If you don't have the absolute path to python36 installed, but another version of python, you know what to do. :)

Comment: You might aswell in your current directory of python 3, do : `python first.py` instead of `first.py` that will search into your PATH.

Comment: God, that was simple. Thank you!